# Windows 10 cant boot to legacy bios

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I've tried all the methods I could find, no luck, cant get to bios.

Funny thing is I managed to get to bios on this machine like 2 months ago, but I dont remember how, it had something to do with "Restart now" from the recovery menu in windows, but that does not seem to work anymore.

The keyboard is working, I can access boot menu after restart, but pressing DEL to access bios does nothing.

Fast startup is off, but I managed to get to bios even when this was on.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know that each individual PC has a way to access BIOS from the boot screen (such as pressing one of the function keys, possibly repeatedly). But if your keyboard is not working, Windows 10 has a way to access BIOS from the GUI. And you're right about the **Restart now** menu option in Windows. To see it, open the Settings app and choose **Update and security > Recovery (on the left) > Restart now (under Advanced startup)**.

Your computer will then restart, and show a blue screen with options - click **Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart**. This method will boot your PC into the BIOS settings that you want. And it lets you do so at your own pace and entirely via a GUI. How user-friendly is *that*?

Images of the process described above can be viewed [at this site](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10).

Comment: I have legacy bios, not UEFI, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Any help from somebody?